# I can't export the blender object

Tags: eclipse, blender

we are doing a android project.We build the 3D object from blender 2.63 but we have been unable to export the object into Eclipse Indigo.We found a solution **blend2java** but it works on lower version of blender up to 2.25.If you found a answer reply us.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what format you want but have you gone to File > Export > File type.
If its not in there go in File > User Preferences > addons > Import/export and look for an addon. Best of luck.